# How to connect Flutter 2.8.1 to Firebase emulator

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-tools

I am working following the latest guidelines:

```
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
```

which of course depends on the firebase_options.dart file:

```
 static const FirebaseOptions android = FirebaseOptions(
    // databaseURL: 'localhost:8080',
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyAwOa9o6tx0UtqrxDO3FmgPUy8roJObDzA',
    appId: '1:853869972316:android:c27448e97b9eb6ec80cf99',
    messagingSenderId: '853869972316',
    projectId: 'favoritelanguage-540b5',
    storageBucket: 'favoritelanguage-540b5.appspot.com',
  );
```

Is there any special setting needed in these files?

My emulator seems to be installed and configured OK:

```
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://localhost:4000                │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator       │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Authentication │ localhost:9099 │ http://localhost:4000/auth      │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore      │ localhost:8080 │ http://localhost:4000/firestore │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Hosting        │ localhost:5000 │ n/a                             │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Storage        │ localhost:9199 │ http://localhost:4000/storage   │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at localhost:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500
```

Issues? Report them at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues and attach the *-debug.log files.

I'm trying to avoid the old way:

```
/// Connnect to the firebase emulator for Firestore and Authentication
Future _connectToFirebaseEmulator() async {
    final localHostString = Platform.isAndroid ? '10.0.2.2' : 'localhost';

FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = Settings(
host: '$localHostString:8080',
sslEnabled: false,
persistenceEnabled: false,
);

await FirebaseAuth.instance.useEmulator('http://$localHostString:9099');
}
```

with

```
Future main() async {
       WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
       await Firebase.initializeApp();

       if (USE_EMULATOR) {
       await _connectToFirebaseEmulator();
     }


     runApp(MyApp());
     }
```

Please help. I'm new to all this.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  if (USE_EMULATOR) {
    // Firestore
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator('localhost', 8080);
    // Auth
    FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator('localhost, 9099');
    // Storage
    FirebaseStorage.instance.bucket = 'default-bucket'; //set bucket first!
    FirebaseStorage.instance.useStorageEmulator('localhost', 9199);
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Perfect Jarrod. I tested this and it works. Thanks a lot!  Andrea Bizzotto also clarified that the use of the CLI and  the emulator are orthogonal: one sets up the access keys (the CLI), and the other defines the connection parameters (   FirebaseFirestore.instance),